# Error when creating a Site Collection for a Site Template

Tags: 2010, site-template, sharepoint-foundation

I'm having some trouble creating a new site template on a customer's system using a site template I've created against our UAT system. Both are using SharePoint 2010 Foundation. The site template creates without any trouble.

When I try to create the new site I see the following errors in the 14/LOGS file:-

```
Failed to read view file "Features\1ECB0.2ListInstances\Files\Lists\CaseNotes\EditForm.aspx".
Failed to read view parameters for view with BaseViewID -1 while creating list "Case Notes" for web "http://servername/sites/sitename".
Failed to provision views and forms. list Case Notes, web http://servername/sites/sitename
Failed to create list "Case Notes" in web "http://servername/sites/sitename", HRESULT=0x10982cd0. List XML: "<List Title="Case Notes" Direction="none" Url="Lists/CaseNotes" BaseType="0" Type="100" BrowserFileHandling="Permissive" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Catalog="FALSE" SendToLocation="|" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" xmlns:spctf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"/>"
Failed to instantiate list 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\CustomList\custlist'
```

When I rename the .wsp to .cab and check, there is an EditForm.aspx listed under the List/CaseNotes folder.  When I check the list via SharePoint Designer, the EditForm.aspx is not shown as an associated form. But if I try to create one it tells me that the file already exists.

Prior to this point it has happily created some of the other custom lists on the site.  So it certainly looks like the EditForm.aspx is the source of the problem but I'm stumped as to where to look for a solution and I've found nothing via Googling.

Has anybody else had this problem and can offer a possible solution?

Cheers!

*** UPDATE 04/10/2011 ***
I've managed to get past this error by creating the EditForm.aspx again. I've created just a standard edit form against the list in SharePoint Designer. Previously it was a customised edit form. Changing this has allowed the site template to be successfully used to create a new site. However, when I try to access the site I get a new error message:-

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist. 

List does not exist. 

The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.<nativehr>0x81020026</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

The SharePoint error logs show this:-

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user. [Managed code transition]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)
```

I've checked the site and can see that all the lists that I expect to be there have been created - so am at a loss to understand why I'm seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around it turned out this problem (part 2) was caused by the use of a web part in our custom master page. I haven't checked whether this would be a problem for coded web parts as well, but for now I've removed the web part and the site template works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on SharePoint 365 so from SharePoint Designer I did the following:

1. Selected **List and Libraries**
2. Selected the list referenced in the error message
3. Under **Settings --> Advanced Settings** unchecked the **Allow Attachments**

*

> NOTE: THIS WILL DELETE ANY AND ALL ATTACHMENTS ASSOCIATED WITH THIS
>   LIST - If you have attachments associated you may want to copy them
>   before making this change

*.